# How to improve Project structure in c# web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, structure, project

I am working on C# web application and i build various application with simple project structure like image is given below.

[image: Solution Explorer]

[image: .cs page]

[image: .aspx page using master page]

Basically i want to know about the best project structure of large web application on C#? or is above project structure(in the image) is right way to build an web application ?

Now i want to improve my project structure. So where should  i start improve myself to build an lage web application.

Answer (score 2):

There's no "best way", but there are some "worst ways". I see that you are using some of the "worst ways". Here are a few of them:

1. Do not use web site "projects". They are not projects. They're just whatever happens to be in a particular directory tree. I notice that you have `~1.pdf` in your project, or did you just happen to have it in the same folder? Use Web Application Projects instead - use File->New Project.
2. Do not use `App_Code`. `App_Code` is for a small number of code files which are compiled at runtime. No other kind of "project" has code compiled at runtime. This is a bizarre corruption of computer programming.

   At the very least, create separate folders for the different parts of your code which are not in code-behind. You can start with a single folder (maybe called "`My_Code`", not `App_Code`), and when you start to get "too many" files in that one folder, start separating the files based on their function. Keep one class per file, and it will become obvious quickly that different sets of classes have different sets of functions. For instance,  you'll find you have a set of classes related to database access. Put those into a "DataAccess" folder.

   Better, once you find that you have many such folders, move each of the folders out into their own class library project. This way, you don't have to jump right into a complex project structure - the structure can evolve over time.

   And if you wind up in ten years with only three classes in `My_Code`, then you have saved yourself the waste of creating tiny class libraries.
3. You may have too much code in your code behind. I can't see it, but projects which have the first two symptoms usually have the third. Your codebehind should only have code in it that directly involves user interface - for instance, it can call a method to fetch data to bind to a data bound control, but the code to *fetch* the data should be in a different class, *not* in the codebehind. This different class should not be in `App_Code`, as I say in #2.
4. Are you using source control? I don't see any source control icons on your project icons. Use source control. [Visual Studio Online](https://www.visualstudio.com/) is free for up to five users, and allows you to use either TFS or Git for source control, as well as providing work item tracking, automated builds and quite a bit more. For free.

Comment: Note that I meant to make this answer cw from the start. All should feel free to elaborate. OTOH, I'll also say that I voted to close the question, which I don't think belongs on [so]. Slightly schizo? Yes and no.

Comment: i think no, you should remove your vote. thanks to answer my question

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is really a correct way to structure a project. It depends on what the goals of the project our and your plans for implementation. Each project is different and have will different requirements.

I would go with the most logical approach for your particular project. Whether that's grouping similar components together or grouping whole sub-systems together.

You should carefully analyze your requirements up front before you even begin development and plan your structure accordingly. Having a good plan before you begin coding will save you a bunch of hassle down-stream if things aren't working out and you need to restructure.

I would suggest reading a book like Code Complete, it'll give you excellent tips on how to plan and structure your projects. You can find it here: [Code Complete](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670)